# Getting "Warning: unprotected private key file!" error message while attempting to import SSH key

Tags: heroku, ssh-keys

Can someone explain this to me please and what I can do to sort out my permissions issue. It seems to be stopping me from getting the authenticity of host `heroku` and fixing my keys issues.

```
david@daniel-Inspiron-531:~$ ssh-add david/.ssh/id_rsa
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
@         WARNING: UNPROTECTED PRIVATE KEY FILE!          @
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
Permissions 0775 for 'david/.ssh/id_rsa' are too open.
It is required that your private key files are NOT accessible by others.
This private key will be ignored.
david@daniel-Ins
```

Answer (score 234, accepted):

I would recommend you to re create a set of keys using

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -C '<email>'
```

for a more secure system. Else changing the permissions to something less open would do.

To change permissions, use

```
chmod  400 ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

Comment: It works. I have 10 servers, i copied the id_rsa from server1 to all other 9 servers then i got this error. To resolve it i applied chmod 400 ~/.ssh/id_rsa and i can now do $ git clone.

Comment: This worked for me :- 
sudo chmod 600 ~/.ssh/id_rsa --
sudo chmod 600 ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub

Comment: either permission could be 400 or 600

Comment: For me only 400 worked, 600 led to a time out while trying to fetch from the github repository

Comment: I tried the equivalent windows method in this link it worked: https://gist.github.com/jaskiratr/cfacb332bfdff2f63f535db7efb6df93

Answer (score 51):

Simply reset permissions to your key files to defaults

```
sudo chmod 600 ~/.ssh/id_rsa
sudo chmod 600 ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
```

Comment: The command for the private key is correct. By other hand, public keys must have read permissions for all. If you limit the permissions to just the user/owner you could have some problems in the future. This command would do the trick `sudo chmod a=r ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` or `sudo chmod 644 ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub`.

Comment: This saved me a lot of time!

Comment: @THEJOATMON that's great to hear!

Answer (score 22):

If you are using WSL, you can copy file.pem to `~/.ssh/`

Copy file .pem

```sh
cp file.pem ~/.ssh/
```

Change permissions:

```sh
chmod 600 ~/.ssh/file.pem
```

Done, try again with your `ssh-add`

```sh
eval `ssh-agent -s`
ssh-add ~/.ssh/file.pem
```

Comment: Thanks Antonio, had to look up this answer twice in 2 weeks, lol!

Answer (score 16):

Just change the permission of the /.ssh/id_rsa file to 600

```
#chmod  600 ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

Answer (score 4):

You should change the owner of the file(which contains the private key)to your username with full access. and then remove the other usernames that have access to that file.

Right Click on the file which contains the private key and clicks on properties and then Security tab> Advanced by clicking on the change button you can change the owner to your username. (if you don't know the name of your username run: "echo %USERNAME%" in command prompt.) Change>Advanced...>Find Now

Remove all Permission entries except the one you just added

click on Disable inheritance> Convert inherited permissions..... then remove all Permission entries except the one you just added.